# Angular material slide toggle capturing state

Tags: angular, angular-material2

I've got a fairly basic slide toggle. I'd like to perform an HTTP call once the slider has been toggled and in case my HTTP call fails, revert it back to the initial value. I've done it as follows:

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { MatSlideToggleChange } from '@angular/material';
import { FakeService } from './fake.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'slide-toggle-configurable-example',
  templateUrl: 'slide-toggle-configurable-example.html'
})
export class SlideToggleConfigurableExample {
  isChecked = false;
  isCheckedInit = false;

  constructor(private readonly fakeService: FakeService) {}

  onChange(value: MatSlideToggleChange) {
    const { checked } = value;

    this.fakeService.throwUp(checked).subscribe(
      () => {},
      () => {
        this.isChecked = this.isCheckedInit;
      }
    );
  }
}
```

However, this doesn't work. My template looks like that:

```html
<mat-slide-toggle
    (change)="onChange($event)"
    [checked]="isChecked">
  Slide me!
</mat-slide-toggle>
<section>
  {{ isChecked }}
</section>
```

But `isChecked` value never changes and is always being displayed as `false`.

It seems that nothing I'm doing on `isChecked` field changes its' value.

Here is a [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-suqsld) to show current behavior.

What do I have to change in order to get desired behavior?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The first thing to do is to bind to `ngModel` instead of `checked`, with 2 way binding, like so:

```
<mat-slide-toggle
    (change)="onChange($event)"
    [(ngModel)]="isChecked">
  Slide me!
</mat-slide-toggle>
```

Secondly, you need to add wrap the this.isChecked = this.isCheckedInit; in a `setTimeout`, so that it doesn't set it to false until material is finished.

```
setTimeout(() => this.isChecked = this.isCheckedInit, 0);
```

**[Here is a Stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-suqsld-pvpkfv?file=app/slide-toggle-configurable-example.html)**

Answer (score 8):

Another option is to use formControl:

In component html:

```html
<mat-slide-toggle [formControl]="toogle">
  Slide me!
</mat-slide-toggle>
```

In the component ts class create a property:

```
toogle = new FormControl('', []);
```

On `ngOnInit()` method of the class:

```js
ngOnInit():void {
   this.toogle.valueChanges.subscribe(newToogleValue=> {
      console.log("toogleValue", newToogleValue);
   });
}
```

And that's all, my friends.